# JSF Composite component iterating and displaying a list of objects

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, composite-component

In JSP and JSTL I would normaly do something like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${userList}" var = "user">
    <div id = "user-block">
        <h1>${user.name}</h1>
        <div id = "user-description">
            <p>${user.description}</p>
        </div>
        <ul>
            <li> Age: ${user.age} </li>
            <li> City: ${user.city} </li>
            <li> Country: ${user.country} </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</c:forEach>
```

I'm trying to gain the same result using Facelet Composite Components:

```
<cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="value" type="java.util.List" required="true" shortDescription="The list of objects that should be displayed"/>
</cc:interface>

<cc:implementation>
    <div class = "event-block">

    </div>
</cc:implementation>
```

The problem is that I don't know how to iterate over the objects in #{cc.attrs.value}.

LE:
*I would like to know if there is a way to solve this without using JSP or JSTL*

Comment: @informatik: please stop tagging JSF questions as `[java]` when the question doesn't concern a basic Java code/language problem (which in turn is essentially unrelated to JSF then). This prevents `[java]` nitwits who are downvoting questions they didn't understand and/or posting nonsensicial comments/answers (and this also prevents default XML/XHTML syntax highlighting being messed up due to higher precedence of `[java]` tag).

Comment: @BalusC Oh, I see. Will take into consideration

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `ui:repeat` instead of `c:forEach`.

```
<ui:repeat value="#{cc.attrs.value}" var="user">
    <h1>#{user.name}</h1>
    ...
</ui:repeat>
```

See https://rogerkeays.com/jsf-c-foreach-vs-ui-repeat for further comparison of `c:forEach` and `ui:repeat`.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the list with `#{cc.attrs.value}`. It would be something like:

```
<c:forEach items="${cc.attrs.value}" var = "user">
   // do your thing
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: I know that but I'm trying to avoid JSP or JSTL completely. Is there no other way?

Comment: Do you have strong reasons for that? It's like you have a gun in front of you and you choose to go into battle empty handed :P

Comment: I'm not saying that I', against it but I figure that there is a way to use only Facelets components to solve this.